# How to handle unsupported metadata types?

Tags: metadata

SalesForce says in his documentation that some things that we can customize in a organization aren’t available in Metadata API. They recommend to document these metadata changes and keep a checklist of these changes to validate migrations or if we want to do it automatically use a browser user interface automation tool. Do you have more tips on how to handle this ? A special tool to help us to track those changes ?

Answer (score 1):

Not everything in Salesforce is represented in the Metadata API as an XML file, and this can create a difficult problem. You can’t deploy these non-XML changes from one environment to another, and so you have to manually re-create the same functionality in each environment. If this requires 15 clicks to accomplish, you have to do those 15 clicks each time, in each org.

Salesforce provides a list of [unsupported Metadata Types](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm) that you need to track changes to yourself. You can find out more about this and means of handling these issues in the [Trailhead Application Lifecycle Management Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/alm_deployment). You'll find a number of links to other resources from within the module.

Comment: Worth also noting that since this original post, the updated metadata coverage report has been made available - makes it a lot more clear what's available via the API and what isn't: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/45